# Cropping is wrong with long formatting text in svg→pdf+pdf_tex

Tags: svg, crop, inkscape

I need to include vector graphics in my document. The text in the graphic needs to be formatted. My current workflow is

- Draw graphic and enter text in "Plain Latex"
- Export/save as SVG
- Convert to PDF + pdf_tex with `inkscape -z -D --file=image.svg --export-pdf=image.pdf --export-latex`
- `\input` image.pdf_tex in Latex document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\frame{
    \def\svgwidth{10cm}
    \input{image.pdf_tex}
}

\end{document}
```

The SVG looks like this ([draw.io-link](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=plainsvgwidth#R7VZNc5swEP013AElNr1Cvi691IeeZbGAJgIxQg64v74rtIApdprO5NQJF63efkja9yQ7YFk9PBveVt91DiqIw3wI2EMQx1GUxDg45OwRxr55oDQyp6AFOMhfQGBI6Enm0K0CrdbKynYNCt00IOwK48bofh1WaLVeteUlbICD4GqL%2FpS5rTy6Y%2BGCv4AsK1r5LiTHkYvX0uhTQ8s1ugHvqflUhUK7iue6v4DYY8Ayo7X1Vj1koFxXp4b5vKcb3nnHBhr7kYS9T3jj6kSHpn3Z89QFTMCG4yTFzbYOFEqfMD%2FtK2nh0HLhwB41gFhla4WzCM2xA%2BAWCn2yP6mblIp3HdlC11KQrfgRVDq3L9NKG3SNDcQS1uhXmMAgZuH4zZ6JJLd4IZW6iCzGz%2BG6sU%2B8lspp8gXUG1gpODlIglFM82tLcSXLBjEFBXY4pf6BsTDc5CCamcW7AroGa84YMiUkJIbpmtC0XzQ366W60Nt8TzjpvJxLL4yjQaRfF0C8FcB9hmexYjz7PjXI4P4BjcwNa19pABrvlVvv0ZUcnWbrnMuKd8uq98qOw2258q71r0IhByfD%2F1yQAuUG5pMkuVtLMtlKMrmiyOQTBHm3EeQPx%2BKfNK%2B5%2FMtL9EX1bapZvKY6ut9yHV17fnb%2FTjZOl5%2B20Xfxz4E9%2FgY%3D))
[image]

The Latex doc looks like this
[image]

Obviously the cropping is bad. How can I fix this?
Note that for some graphics the text is supposed to be outside any forms, so I guess you can't just crop the image.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Rereading your question, I think this is no good, since sometimes your text will be outside the drawing but you can't know in advance it's dimensions. Sorry! I'll leave this answer for the moment in case it helps you or others.

---

I suggest that you resize your page in `inkscape` to the drawing excluding the text (i.e., so that your long text overlaps the page).

Then export with the `-C` flag (crop to page area), rather than the `-D` flag (crop to drawing area).

i.e.,

```
inkscape -z -C --file=image.svg --export-pdf=image.pdf --export-latex
```